# Blazorise sidebar: how to toggle SidebarSubItem side by side?

Tags: c#, css, blazor, bulma, blazorise

I'd like to toggle Blazorise Bulma SideBarSubItem on the right hand side of the Sidebar, the current Sidebar is similar to the demo here https://bulmademo.blazorise.com/. The code for the "UI Elements" is like this (I've removed some unnecessary elements):

```
<Sidebar @ref="sidebar">
    <SidebarContent>
        <SidebarNavigation>
             <SidebarItem>
                  <SidebarLink Toggled="(isOpen)=> sidebarSubItemUIElement.Toggle(isOpen)" Visible="true">
                        <Icon Name="IconName.Edit" Margin="Margin.Is3.FromRight" />UI Elements
                  </SidebarLink>
                  <SidebarSubItem @ref="sidebarSubItemUIElement" Visible="true">
                        <SidebarItem>
                            <SidebarLink To="tests/buttons">Buttons</SidebarLink>
                        </SidebarItem>
                        <SidebarItem>
                            <SidebarLink To="tests/modals">Modals</SidebarLink>
                        </SidebarItem>
                  </SidebarSubItem>
             </SidebarItem>
        </SidebarNavigation>
    </SidebarContent>
</Sidebar>
```

If toggle "UI Elements", by default the SubItems are dropped underneath. In my case I have lots of SubItems, so I'd like to toggle them to the right hand side, as shown here:

[image]

My idea was to change to `<SidebarItem Style="display: flex">` above the `<SidebarLink>`, but it makes the SubItems squeezed in the Sidebar like this:

[image]

Any idea how I can do it?